# Scala - JSON object is polymorphic on a field type

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-cats

I'm attempting to decode some truly terrible JSON. The type information for each object is encoded within a field labeled `type` , i.e. `"type": "event"`, etc. I'm using [Circe](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/) for JSON encoding / decoding.  The library utilizes typeclasses, where the relevant typeclass is `def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[A]`.  The issue is that any Decoder is invariant to type, `A`.  Here is a concrete example

```
sealed trait MotherEvent {
  val id: UUID
  val timestamp: DateTime
}
implicit val decodeJson: Decoder[MotherEvent] = new Decoder[MotherEvent] { 
def apply(c: HCursor) = {
  c.downField("type").focus match {
    case Some(x) => x.asString match {
      case Some(string) if string == "flight" => FlightEvent.decodeJson(c)
      case Some(string) if string == "hotel"  => // etc 
      // like a bunch of these
      case None => Xor.Left(DecodingFailure("type is not a string", c.history))
    }
    case None    => Xor.Left(DecodingFailure("not type found", c.history))
  }
}

sealed trait FlightEvents(id: UUID, timestamp: DateTime, flightId: Int)
case class Arrival(id: UUID, timestamp: DateTime, flightId: Int) extends Event // a metric ton of additional fields
case class Departure(id: UUID, timestamp: DateTime, flightId: Int) extends Event // samsies as Arrival
```

Decoding works fine, but `MotherEvent` is always returned

```
val jsonString = // from wherevs, where the json string is flightevent
val x = decode[MotherEvent](jsonString)
println(x) // prints (cats.data.Xor[io.circe.Error, MotherEvent] = Right(FlightEvent)
println(x.flightId) // ERROR- flightId is not a member of MotherEvent
```

Of course, I would like to have a FlightEvent instead of mother event. One possible solution is to create a "mother" type that has 60 or 70 fields, but I already hate myself and want to quit programming just thinking about 70 `Option[A]` fields that are filled based off the `type` field.

Can anyone think of a good solution to this?

Comment: I don't know Circe, but somehow it looks like you could just cast the result: `x match {case Right(FlightEvent(_, _, flightId)) => println(flightId); case _ => }`.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good solution here (or at least one that doesn't involve code generation, something type-provider-ish, `Dynamic`, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I ended up embracing an invariant `A` and leaning on Shapeless for a `Coproduct`.  This lead to some additional code duplication, but it dramatically simplified how I thought about the problem and how the `Decoder[A]` was handled. As this is part of a simple data ingest program, it was relatively easy to map the additional work over the `Coproduct` and have cleaner types for the data as represented by the DB.  Here's a toy example of how this came together:

```
import shapeless._
import io.circe._, io.circe.Decoder.instance 

case class FlightEvent(id: UUID, departureTime: DateTime, arrivalTime: DateTime)
case class HotelEvent(id: UUID, city: String)
case class CarEvent(id: UUID, carrier: String)
// assume valid Decoder typeclasses in each companion object

type FHC = FlightEvent :+: HotelEvent :+: CarEvent :+: CNil
type FHCs = List[FHC]

implicit val decodeFHC: Decoder[FHC] = instance { c => 
  c.downField("type".focus match {
    case Some(t) => t.asString match {
      case Some(string) if string == "flight" => FlightEvent.decodeJson(c) map { Coproduct[FHC](_) }
      case Some(string) if string == "hotel"  => HotelEvent.decodeJson(c) map { Coproduct[FHC](_) }
      case Some(string) if string == "car"    => CarEvent.decodeJson(c) map { Coproduct[FHC](_) }
      case Some(string) => Xor.Left(DecodingFailure(s"unkown type $string", c.history))
      case None =>  Xor.Left(DecodingFailure("json field \"type\", string expected", c.history))
    }
    case None => Xor.Left(DecodingFailure("json field \"type\" not found", c.history))
  }
}
```

This was my first time employing shapeless, so there's a high chance that there is a cleaner way to implement this.  I did enjoy how orthogonal `Coproduct` made this.